# Как перехватить СМС состоящее из 2 или 3 СМС из приложения для андроид

Tags: android, java

Мой ресивер, он отлично работает когда приходят короткие смс, но при больших, перехватывает кусками.

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onReceive()");
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        SmsMessage[] phonenum = null;//

        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                body += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            // ---retrieve the SMS senders number ---
            phonenum = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < phonenum.length; i++) {
                phonenum[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                PhoneNUMBER += phonenum[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }
```

Получается так, что если приходит большое сообщение, состоящее из 2 или 3 смс, то он его полностью не берет, а помещает в переменную body, только первую часть, а остальные вообще не обрабатывает. Получается пользователь видит первое СМС, цельной картины не видит, а остальные смс приходят обычным путем, через уведомление. 
       Так вот хотел узнать как перехватывать такие сообщения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Держи кусочек код для перехвата мультипартных смсок. Возвращает `Map<String address, String text>`:

```
private Map<String, String> retrieveMessages(Intent intent) {
    Map<String, String> msg = null;
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null && bundle.containsKey("pdus")) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        if (pdus != null) {
            int nbrOfpdus = pdus.length;
            msg = new HashMap<String, String>(nbrOfpdus);
            msgs = new SmsMessage[nbrOfpdus];
            // There can be multiple SMS from multiple senders, there can be a maximum of nbrOfpdus different senders
            // However, send long SMS of same sender in one message
            for (int i = 0; i < nbrOfpdus; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                String originatinAddress = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                // Check if index with number exists
                if (!msg.containsKey(originatinAddress)) {
                    // Index with number doesn't exist
                    // Save string into associative array with sender number as index
                    msg.put(msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress(), msgs[i].getMessageBody());
                } else {
                    // Number has been there, add content but consider that
                    // msg.get(originatinAddress) already contains sms:sndrNbr:previousparts of SMS,
                    // so just add the part of the current PDU
                    String previousparts = msg.get(originatinAddress);
                    String msgString = previousparts + msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    msg.put(originatinAddress, msgString);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return msg;
}
```

**Update**

Вызов:

```
Map<String, String> msgs = retrieveMessages(intent);
for (String address : msgs.keySet()) 
     String msg = msgs.get(address); //сообщение от адресата
```

Comment: Большое спасибо конечно, но для меня хэш-карта пока сложновата в понимании. Не сочтите за наглость, как этим методом пользоваться?
Мне надо создать хэш-карту, 
Map staff = new HashMap< String, Employee>();
вызвать метод 
staff = retrieveMessages(intent); 
из метода onReceive, 
он вернет карту ее надо присвоить хеш-карте, правильно?, а как из карты получить стринговые значения? 
Такой метод подойдёт?
for (Map.Entry entry: staff.entrySet()) { 
String key = entry.getKey(); 
Employee value = entry.getValue(); 
}

Comment: @FFFNikolay как вы можете что-то пытаться писать не понимая как работает примитивнейшая Java коллекция? Смотрите апдейт.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что это выглядит глупо. Просто в начале хотел создать простенькое приложение, подучил немного java и начал кодить для андроид, ну а сейчас уже понял, что java надо учить получше. На ней все завязано, сейчас уже доделаю, да начну. У меня есть Герберт Шилд 2012 и Васильев А.Н. 2011, по вашему они те, с чьих книг надо начинать изучение? Или подскажите автора. Ну а за Update спасибо.

Comment: Ну не Васильев это точно. Шилд неплох, но он то сам не прогер. Раньше была книжка Питера Нортона про Java - (давно правда). Я считаю это лучшей книжкой - найти наверное сейчас сложно будет. Так что читайте Шилда.

Comment: Трудно советовать начинающим. 

Посмотрите Хорстманн (двухтомник Java 2).  На мой вкус все несколько затянуто, но в приципе понравилось.

Comment: @FFFNikolay - это пипец... Включите мозги и подумайте...

Comment: Проверил все работает теперь сообщение при помощи вашего метода перехватывается полностью, прям обалденный метод, буду всегда им пользоваться, большое спасибо, а адрес я по старому извлекаю, так тоже работает.

Comment: @FFFNikolay адрес же уже приходит в массиве ключей `Map<String, String>` - ну дурная голова рукам покоя не дает?

Comment: Что-то вроде этого. Согласен, адрес там тоже есть. Да я и так и так пробовал, не получается его извлечь, то одно красным, то другое.

Comment: Если красным значит вы неверно пишете синтаксис. Адрес извлекается в цикле: `for (String address : msgs.keySet())`

Comment: @FFFNikolay, по русски "hash map" будет "хeш-таблица", не "хеш-карта"

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй так

```
String message;
```

...

```
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] messages=new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++) {
                messages[i]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }

        message = getMessageFromSMSs( messages);
```

....

```
private String getMessageFromSMSs(SmsMessage[] sms) {
        String str="";
        for(SmsMessage message:sms) {
                str += message.getMessageBody().toString();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

...

```
 String phoneNumber=messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проверил работает, лучше моего(хоть все сообщение обрабатывает), но если получается большая задержка где-то 15-25 сек., то разбивает на два, это исправить нельзя?